# How to Deserialize the current object

Tags: java, file, serialization, stream, deserialization

I have created a bankStatement program and there are two classes such as **Main** and **FinancialManager**.In this program I can withdraw, deposit and see current Account balance.
this is my **FinancialManager** class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class FinancialManager implements Serializable {
    private double balance1;
    private Vector<String> statement1;
    public FinancialManager(){
        balance1=0;
        statement1 = new Vector<String>();
    }
    public void deposit(double value){
        balance1 = balance1+value;
        String st = "Deposit  "+String.valueOf(value);
        statement1.add(st);
    }
    public void withdraw(double value){
        if(value<balance1){
            balance1 = balance1 - value;
            String st = "Withdraw "+String.valueOf(value);
            statement1.add(st);
        }else{
            String st = "Withdraw 0.0";
            statement1.add(st);
        }
    }
    public String balance(){
        return String.valueOf(balance1);
    }
    public void statement(){
        String[] array = statement1.toArray(new String[statement1.size()]);
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public void save(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
            // write "this" - the current object - to the file
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);
        }
    }

}
```

And my Main class is below

```
public class Main {
    public static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FinancialManager fm = new FinancialManager();
        fm.deposit(25.00);
        fm.withdraw(12.00);
        fm.deposit(10.00);
        fm.deposit(5.00);
        fm.withdraw(8.00);
        System.out.println("The current balance is "+fm.balance());
        fm.statement();
        fm.save("text.txt");

        FinancialManager anotherfm = new FinancialManager();

    }
}
```

I could create the **Serialization** method in my **FinancialManager** using this keyword.but I don't know how to create **Deserialization** method.how can I do that?
Please help me with this.The method should be like this in **FinancialManager** class.

```
public void load(String filename){
   //Write your code here
}
```

Need to use this method in Main class like this

```
FinancialManager anotherFM = new FinancialManager(); 
anotherFM.load(laccountl");
anotherFM.statement();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desrialisation creates the object. The object shouldn't already exist. Therefore make in `static`, the same as a creation method (such as `List.of`).

However, [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#8)  says:

> **Note: Deserialization of untrusted data is inherently dangerous and
>   should be avoided.**

I wouldn't touch Java Serialization.